# From JSON to JSON-LD without changing the source

Tags: python, json, rdf, json-ld

There are 'duplicates' to my question but they don't answer my question.

Considering the following JSON-LD example as described in paragraph 6.13 - Named Graphs from http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/:

```
{
    "@context": {
    "generatedAt": {
    "@id": "http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#generatedAtTime",
    "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"
    },
    "Person": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person",
    "name": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name",
    "knows": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows"
    },
    "@id": "http://example.org/graphs/73",
    "generatedAt": "2012-04-09",
    "@graph":
             [
                  {
                   "@id": "http://manu.sporny.org/about#manu",
                   "@type": "Person",
                   "name": "Manu Sporny",
                   "knows": "http://greggkellogg.net/foaf#me"
                   },
                   {
                   "@id": "http://greggkellogg.net/foaf#me",
                   "@type": "Person",
                   "name": "Gregg Kellogg",
                   "knows": "http://manu.sporny.org/about#manu"
                   }
             ]
}
```

Question:

What if you start with only the JSON part without the semantic layer:

```
[{
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "knows": "http://greggkellogg.net/foaf#me"
},
{
  "name": "Gregg Kellogg",
  "knows": "http://manu.sporny.org/about#manu"
}]
```

and you link the @context from a separate file or location using a http link header or rdflib parsing, then you are still left without the @id and @type in the rest of the document. Injecting those missing keys-values into the json string is not a clean option. The idea is to go from JSON to JSON-LD without changing the original JSON part.

The way I see it to define a triple subject, one has to use an @id to map tot an IRI. It's very unlikely that JSON data has the @id key-values. So does this mean all JSON files cannot be parsed as JSON-LD without add the keys first? I wonder how they do it.
Does someone have an idea to point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately that's not possible. There exist, however, libraries and tools that have been created exactly for that reason. [JSON-LD Macros](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/json-ld-macros) is such a library. It allows declarative transformations of JSON objects to make them usable as JSON-LD. So, effectively, all you need is a very thin layer on top of an off-the-shelve JSON-LD processor.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for.